# Invert a shapefile with GDAL

Tags: shapefile, gdal

How do I invert a shapefile with GDAL? Basically, I have a global water body shapefile. I'd like to ask the question "does this filter region intersect *land*?" The most obvious way to do this is to invert (or complement) the shapefile and then use the OGRLayer filter functionality.

Unfortunately I can't just go an grab an arbitrary land shapefile -- I have to use this water body shapefile specifically.

EDIT:

I have a water body shapefile:

[image: representation of a water body shapefile]

I would like to invert it (in other words, get it's complement or reverse the polygon winding direction) in to a land mass shapefile:

[image: inversion of the previous shape file]

(Colors aren't important here except for illustrative purposes.)

Comment: Can you include screen shots of what you are viewing now and/or possible the result you are looking for ?

Comment: I've added an illustration of what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but: Make a global polygon (rectangle), then subtract your water polygon from this one. Use "Difference" in QGIS or "Erase" in Arc.

Comment: I'll give it a shot with QGIS (TIL QGIS is a thing -- I'm a computer scientist, not a GIS expert).

Comment: Are there many islands or just one?

Comment: It's a global coastline shapefile.

Comment: Please add what you get with `ogrinfo -so al your_shapefile.shp`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you want GDAL specifically - that is really a library which concentrates on format conversions amongst other things. [Geos](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) is probably the base library that you want, and it happens to be behind the hood of many GIS software packages such as QGIS and PostGIS.

If you need a higher layer abstraction, then I would recommend Shapely in Python, specifically read the bit about [Spatial Analysis methods](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#spatial-analysis-methods) such as the difference algorithm above.

Not sure the concept of winding you mention above will be much use here for a shapefile or any other GIS file, as you need a bounding box for your shape, and it's unlikely that any GIS tool would allow you to invert a shape across the whole surface of the earth / some other projection due to computational and usability concerns. If it did the resulting file would likely be huge and  subject to strange artefacts/distortion at the edges of the projection area, e.g. the poles when projecting on the WGS84 (Lat/Lon) sphere. So you need to define your area of interest, the rectangle as proposed above.